# LaTeX count number of occurrences of a character in a string

Tags: strings

Let's say I have some string `This~is a ~test`. I need to count the number of `~` characters. Is there some way to do this in LaTeX?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `expl3` you can split the *token list* into *items* and then count the *items* (less 1):

> 2
>   4

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% \CountSubStr{<substring>}{<string>}
\NewDocumentCommand{\CountSubStr}{ m m }{
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { #1 } { #2 }
  \int_eval:n {(\seq_count:N \l_tmpa_seq) - 1 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\CountSubStr{~}{This~is a ~test}% 2

\CountSubStr{yes}{a yes b yes c yes deyesfg yehs ij}% 4

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

For good measure, a LuaLaTeX-based solution:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode} % for '\luastring' and '\luaexec' macros
\newcommand\tildecount[1]{\luaexec{
   _ , count = string.gsub ( \luastring{#1} , "~" , "~" )
   tex.sprint ( count ) }}
\begin{document}
\tildecount{This~is a ~test}

\tildecount{~~~~----&&&&****____####~~~~$$$$~~~~}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: The `\tildecount` macro can easily be generalized to take a second input, *viz.*, the string whose occurrences should be counted. The code for the generalized macro would be as follows:

```
\newcommand\StringCount[2]{\luaexec{
   _ , count = string.gsub ( \luastring{#2} , \luastring{#1} , "" )
   tex.sprint ( count ) }}
```

This macro may be used, for instance, as

```
\StringCount{yes}{a yes b yes c yes desyesfg mess ij}
```

(result: 4) or as

```
\StringCount{es}{a yes b mesh c best less xxDavieszz mess ij}
```

(result: 6).

Answer (score 1):

A `listofitems` approach.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\countem[2]{%
  \setsepchar{#1}%
  \readlist\countlist{#2}%
  \the\numexpr\listlen\countlist[]-1\relax
}
\begin{document}
\countem{~}{This~is a ~test}

\countem{es}{a yes b mesh c best less xxDavieszz mess ij} 
\end{document}
```

The MWE gives the appropriate answers of `2` and `6`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\countin}{smm}
 {% #1 = * if searching in a macro
  % #2 = string to search
  % #3 = token list to search in
  \IfBooleanTF { #1 }
   {
    \bruoga_countin:nV { #2 } #3
   }
   {
    \bruoga_countin:nn { #2 } { #3 }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \bruoga_countin:nn
 {
  \regex_count:nnN { #1 } { #2 } \l_tmpa_int
  \int_to_arabic:n { \l_tmpa_int }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \bruoga_countin:nn { nV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mytl}{This~is a ~test}

\countin{~}{This~is a ~test}

\countin*{~}{\mytl}

\countin{t}{This~is a ~test}

\countin{[Tt]}{This~is a ~test}

\countin{[aeiou]}{This~is a ~test}

\end{document}
```

This prints

> 2
>   2
>   2
>   3
>   4

The syntax for (simple) regular expressions is quite standard.

Comment: Using your solution, I have managed to count a character within an argument by assigning the argument to a macro `\def\labelvalue{#1}\def\coloncount{\countin*{:}{\labelvalue}}`. Printing the result works fine, but unfortunately `Missing number, treated as zero. <to be read again> \xparse function is not expandable` is being thrown when comparing the result with an integer, e.g. `\ifnum \coloncount=1`. I found this  [link](https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=2020) mentioning your answer, but I didn't get their suggestion to work. Do you have any suggestions on how to make this work?

Comment: @coreuter Please, ask a new question with the details as a followup to this one.

Comment: thank you very much for your prompt reply! I have asked a new question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/692035/96582

Answer (score 0):

Consider [`substr.sty`](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/nicetext/demo/substr.pdf).

Add `\usepackage{substr}` and try

```
\CountSubStrings{~}{This~is a ~test} % -> 2
```

or

```
\newcounter{foo}
\SubStringsToCounter{foo}{;}{1;2;3;4}
\stepcounter{foo}
% \thefoo -> 4
```