# Clash somewhere among \fpeval, \or, and \CountToken

Tags: macros, counters, floating-point

(This is my first question here, sorry for any "side effects" of it...)

I'd like to implement that, depending on the value of `\MyR` (a number between 0 and 1, 1 excluded), the first/second/... item of a set would be chosen. In the MWE below, a set is realized in the format `{item1\or item2\or item3 ...}`. If, for example, a set has two elements: `{item1\or item2}` then, for values of `\MyR` below 0.5, `item1` would be returned, and for values above 0.5, `item2` is to be returned. From a set `{item1\or item2\or item3}`, 0.33 would yield `item1` while 0.34 would lead to `item2`. Below I use `\ifcase`, and compute which of its branches should be returned.

Version `(*)` (see below, implementation via `\newcommandFromSet`) seems to work. Hovewer, the variants `(**)` and `(***)` (two attempts for `\FromSet`) fail when we uncomment the last (but one) line `%\fpeval...`.
The success of `(*)` seems to justify the basic concept, but how could I cure the definition of `\FromSet`? Thank you!

([Link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/525556/%20token-counter-strange-behaviour-of-math-mode) to @egreg's `\CountToken`.)

[A format `{item1\SomeShortToken item2\SomeShortToken item3 ...}` would be easy to
type, and calculating the number of items would also be for user
convenience.]

```
\documentclass{article}  %% MWE
\usepackage{xfp}

\def\finish{\finish}                    %% Frequency of token #1 (stored
\def\CountToken[#1,#2]{%                %% in counter #2) in what's
  \def\TestedToken{#1}%                 %% between \CountToken[#1,#2]
  \ifdefined#2#2=0 \else\newcount#2\fi  %% and \finish. Code copied from
  \let\TotalOccurrence#2%               %% https://tex.stackexchange.com
  \let\next\TestNext\next               %% questions/525556/token-
}                                       %% counter-strange-behaviour-
\long\def\TestNext#1{%                  %% of-math-mode (egreg's version)
  \def\CurrentToken{#1}%                %%
  \ifx\CurrentToken\finish              %%
    \let\next\relax                     %%
  \else                                 %%
    \ifx\CurrentToken\TestedToken       %%
      \advance\TotalOccurrence by 1     %%
    \fi                                 %%
  \fi                                   %%
  \next                                 %%
}                                       %%

\newcommand{\MyR}{0.67}  %% my "global variable".

\newcommand{\newcommandFromSet}[2]{\CountToken[\or,\cnti]#2\finish  %% (*)
  \xdef#1{\ifcase\fpeval{floor(\MyR*(1+\cnti))} #2\fi}}
\newcommand{\FromSet}[1]{\CountToken[\or,\cnti]#1\finish  %% (**)
          \ifcase\fpeval{floor(\MyR*(1+\cnti))} #1\fi}
%\renewcommand{\FromSet}[1]{\newcommandFromSet{\MyTemp}{#1}\MyTemp}  %% (***)

\begin{document}
\newcommandFromSet{\MyText}{first\or second\or third}
\newcommandFromSet{\MyNumber}{11\or 12\or 13}
The \MyText\ number is \MyNumber, I repeat,
\fpeval{1*\MyNumber}.  %% everything seems to be good.

The \FromSet{first\or second\or third} number is  %% this line seems to work.
\FromSet{11\or 12\or 13}, I repeat,  %% this line also seems to work.
%\fpeval{1*\FromSet{\or 11\or 12\or 13}}.  %% ! Extra \or. \TestedToken ->\or
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. I didn't understand what you want to do or your problem.

Comment: I hope the edited version explains the situation better.

Comment: Are you ***sure*** you want to count `\or` tokens with code that exploits `\ifcase`? That's quite likely the source of your problem. I'm quite confident that the second version in the answer you refer to doesn't suffer from the problem.

Comment: The implementation via `\or` and `\ifcase` is not necessary (just one seemingly plausible way), and it does work in the form of `\newcommandFromSet`. Nevertheless, more generally, I would be satisfied with any `\SomeShortToken` – or, say, a semicolon – in a format `{item1\SomeShortToken item2\SomeShortToken item3 ...}`. The format itself I find user-friendly, and I would like LaTeX to calculate the number of items (rather than the user).

Comment: @egreg if you refer to the `expl3` version: For the users I have in mind, the syntax of `expl3` would be somewhat intimidating, I'm afraid… (I mean, they would also take a look at the preamble.)

Comment: @TFulop Explain it! :-) Wouldn't they be intimidated also by that cryptic code with `\CountToken`?

Comment: This would be used in teaching, and I would take this opportunity to advocate/encourage using LaTeX among my colleagues, who are much more beginners than me. (I'm a beginner for >20 years: a slowly evolving one.) I would like to give them confidence that they can master LaTeX. With that eye, the syntax of `expl3`…

Comment: E.g., they still get accustomed to that, unlike in other programming languages (OK, TeX is not exactly a programming language), here, `_`, numbers, and other 'exotic' characters are not allowed in command names. Their eyes still need training to learn what syntax is TeX-ish and what is not. A `\CountToken` is more consistent with their level, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `\or` in that context, I'm afraid. But the code can be made much simpler.

I'd prefer comma separated items, rather than separated by `\or`, so the `\FromSet` macro is fully expandable.

With `\clist_count:n` we can access expandably the number of items, so we can scale the variable by it; then truncate and add 1.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\newcommandFromSet}{O{\MyR}mm}
 {
  \cs_new:Npx #2
   {
    \clist_item:nn { #3 }
     {
      \fp_eval:n { trunc(#1*\clist_count:n { #3 },0) + 1 }
     }
   }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\FromSet}{O{\MyR}m}
 {
  \clist_item:nn { #2 }
   {
    \fp_eval:n { trunc(#1*\clist_count:n { #2 },0) + 1 } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\MyR}{0.67}  %% my "global variable".
\newcommand{\MyS}{0.1}  %% another "global variable".

\begin{document}

\newcommandFromSet{\MyText}{first,second,third}
\newcommandFromSet{\MyNumber}{,11,12,13}

The \MyText\ number is \MyNumber, I repeat,
\fpeval{1*\MyNumber}.

The \FromSet{first,second,third} number is
\FromSet{11,12,13}, I repeat,
\fpeval{1*\FromSet{11,12,13}}.

\newcommandFromSet[\MyS]{\MyTextA}{first,second,third}
\newcommandFromSet[\MyS]{\MyNumberA}{11,12,13}

The \MyTextA\ number is \MyNumberA, I repeat,
\fpeval{1*\MyNumberA}.

The \FromSet[\MyS]{first,second,third} number is
\FromSet[\MyS]{11,12,13}, I repeat,
\fpeval{1*\FromSet[\MyS]{11,12,13}}.

\end{document}
```

Note that you can use *different* variables; the default is `\MyR`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @egreg. Unfortunately, my `\MyR` will be restricted between 0 and 1 so I need to determine the number of elements of a given set in order to calculate which item to return.

Comment: @TFulop I misunderstood. With a change of syntax it's doable quite easily. I wouldn't use `\or`.

Comment: Thank you (as a newcomer, my upvote is not displayed)… I've also tried to modify your code to `;` as the separator (I'm from a country with decimal comma), but failed. And `|` as the separator gave a funny result. What separators would be allowed? Or how about an `\OR`?

Comment: @TFulop Sorry, but `;` would make the macros not expandable. Just brace numbers that have a comma in them.

Comment: If I try `\fpeval{1*\FromSet[\MyS]{{1,1},{1,2},{1,3}}}.` as the last but one line, the output is surprising.

Comment: @TFulop `\fpeval` doesn't accept a comma as the decimal separator. Sorry, but you can do nothing about it. Use `\num` from `siunitx` for *displaying* numbers and always use the decimal period for the input.

Comment: I see; only `siunitx` is such liberal with the decimal comma. We will cope with the decimal point and the braces (for text items containing a comma). Thank you!