# Counting the number of occurences of specific characters in a string in an expandable way

Tags: expl3, expansion, characters, programming, strings

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/336295/17200) shows how to count the number of occurrences of a specific character in a string. I would like to do it in an expandable way, and for a list (not only one) of specific characters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\countsep}{r[] m}{
    % CODE HERE
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\countsep[-+]{This-is-a+test} % Count the number of - and + in the string (3)
\countsep[-+]{T+h+i+s-is-a-test} % Count the number of - and + in the string (6)
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is "string" meant to really be string, or do you mean token lists (for instance, is `\countsep[+]{a\+b}` 0 or 1)? What about things nested inside braces (is `\countsep[+]{a+b{+c}}` 1 or 2)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\countsep#1#2{\the\numexpr0\countsepy#1\Endlist#2\Endcount}
\def\countsepy#1#2\Endlist#3\Endcount{\countsepz#1#3\Endcount
  \ifx\relax#2\relax\relax\else\countsepy#2\Endlist#3\Endcount\fi}
\def\countsepz#1#2#3\Endcount{\ifx#1#2+1\fi
  \ifx\relax#3\relax\else\countsepz#1#3\Endcount\fi}

\begin{document}
\countsep{-}{This-is-a+test} % Count the number of - in the string (2)
\countsep{+}{This-is-a+test} % Count the number of + in the string (1)
\countsep{-+}{This-is-a+test} % Count the number of - and + in the string (3)

\edef\z{\countsep{-+}{T+h+i+s-is-a-test}}
\z
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How would one have to modify `\countsep` so that `\def\yy{T} \def\zz{TTT} \countsep{\yy}{\zz}` and `\countsep{ß}{ßßß}` would work? (The latter case concerns utf8-encoded characters.)

Comment: @Mico The syntax `\countsep{äÖÜß}{ßT+h+i+s-is-a-testäÖÜß}` will already work as is, if the code is compiled in lualatex or xelatex. As to the case of `\countsep{\yy}{\zz}`, I could probably tweak a solution to meet your interpretation; however, I would prefer to interpret the syntax without any expansion of the arguments, such that `\countsep{\today}{xy\today z\today pdq}` would directly yield the result `2`, which my code will do.

Comment: @Mico For example, `\def\yy{T} \def\zz{TTT} 
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\countsep\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\yy\expandafter}\expandafter{\zz}` would accomplish a single expansion of each argument, which could be codified into a macro.  Likewise, `\expanded{\noexpand\countsep{\yy}{\zz}}` for full expansion.  But as I said, it makes more sense to me to interpret the arguments unexpanded.

Comment: Thanks for these additional explanations.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution for `\countsep`. The solution is a simple refinement of a [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/336299/5001) I gave to the [earlier query](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/336294/5001) mentioned in the OP's posting. Note that `\countsep` is expandable because `\directlua` and `\luastring` are expandable.

Observe further that both the search string and the target string can include general UTF8-encoded characters.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode} % for '\luastring' macro
\newcommand\countsep[2]{\directlua{%
   _ , count = unicode.utf8.gsub ( "#2" , "["..\luastring{#1}.."]" , "" )
   tex.sprint ( count ) }}

\def\yy{äÖÜß}
\def\zz{ßT+h+i+s-is-a-testäÖÜß}
\edef\z{\countsep{\yy}{\zz}}

\begin{document}
\countsep{""}{This-is-a+test} % result: 0
\countsep{-+}{This-is-a+test} % result: 3
\countsep{-+}{T+h+i+s-is-a-test} % result: 6
\countsep{\yy}{\zz\zz} % result: 10
\z % result: 5
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following implements this in L3 using `etl`. It does use the required argument in brackets of your question, though I strongly advice against it. Using non-standard arguments is discouraged for a reason, `[]` is usually an optional argument, which this isn't, and I see no good reason for the parsing overhead here.

Things to mention:

- this assumes you want to actually count occurences in a token list (no stringification)
- this assumes separators inside braces are to be counted (if not change the nested `+ \vincent_count_tokens_in:nn` to `\use_none:nn`)
- This counts correctly if one of the specified separators is a space
- This doesn't work for non-ASCII separator-symbols in non-UTF8-engines (pdfTeX), otherwise it works in all engine

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse, etl}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\etl_new_if_in:Nnn \__vincent_if_contains_space:n { ~ } { T }
\cs_new:Npn \vincent_count_tokens_in:nn #1#2
  {
    \int_eval:w 0
    \etl_act:nennn
      \__vincent_count_tokens_in:nN
      {
        \__vincent_if_contains_space:nT {#1} { + \c_one_int }
        \use_none:n
      }
      { + \vincent_count_tokens_in:nn }
      {#1}
      {#2}
    \scan_stop:
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \etl_act:nnnnn { ne }
\cs_new:Npn \__vincent_count_tokens_in:nN #1#2
  { \etl_token_if_in:nNT {#1} #2 { + \c_one_int } }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\countsep}{r[] m}
  { \vincent_count_tokens_in:nn {#1} {#2} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\countsep[-+]{This-is-a+test} % Count the number of - and + in the string (3)
\countsep[- +]{T+h+i+s is{-a-}test} % Count the number of -, space and + in the string (6)
\end{document}
```

---

Aside: This is not particularly fast, as `etl` has to check for spaces and groups for each list element, so it does much more in the background than the solution by @StevenB.Segletes, this is only needed if you really want to be able to count spaces, and/or recurse into groups.